# Error the GET method is not supported for route api/Login. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm developing a project in PHP Laravel and React.

I have a login screen in react where I make an axios request to the PHP API in the api.php file, however even though axios is defined as post and my route in the API I also receive the error:

> The GET method is not supported for route api/ Login. Supported methods: POST.

I've tried several solutions but they all tell me the same solution. Both methods should be posted, but they are already like this.

api.php file code:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers;


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
});
    Route::post('/Logout', [AuthController::class, 'Logout']);
    Route::get('/Users', [Controllers\UserController::class, 'index']);
});

Route::post('/CadastrarUsuario', [AuthController::class, 'CadastrarUsuario']);
Route::post('/Login', [AuthController::class, 'Login']);
```

router.jsx file code:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";


import DefaultLayout from "./components/DefaultLayout";
import AuthenticatedLayout from "./components/AuthenticatedLayout";

{/* Rotas padrão */}
import Home from "./views/SemAuteticacao/Home";
import Login from "./views/SemAuteticacao/Login";
import Dashboard from "./views/Autenticada/Dashboard";
import Signup from "./views/SemAuteticacao/Signup";
import NotFound from "./views/NotFound";

const router = (
    <Routes>
       
        <Route
            path="/"
            element={<DefaultLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/Signup" element={<Signup/>} />
        </Route>

     
        <Route
            path="/admin"
            element={<AuthenticatedLayout />}>
            <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>

  
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
);

export default router;
```

login.jsx file code:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {useRef, useState} from "react";
import {useStateContext} from "../context/ContextProvider.jsx";
import axiosClient from "../../axios-client.js";

export default function Login(){

  const emailRef = useRef();
  const senhaRef = useRef();

  const {setUser, setToken} = useStateContext()
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null)
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)

  const onSubmit = (ev) =>
  {
    ev.preventDefault()
    const payload =
      {
        email: emailRef.current.value,
        password: senhaRef.current.value,
      }
    console.log(payload)
    setErrors( null )
    axiosClient.post('/Login', payload)
      //Se os dados estiverem corretos executa isso
      .then(({data}) => {
        setUser(data.user)
        setToken(data.token)

      }).catch( err => {
      const response = err.response;
      if(response && response.status == 422)
      {
        //Erros genericos
        if(response.data.errors)
        {
          console.log(response.data.errors)
          setErrors(response.data.errors)
        }
        //email existe mas senha errada
        else
        {
          console.log(response.data.message)
          setErrors({
            email:[response.data.message]
          })
        }

      }
    })
  }

    return (
        <div className="login-signup-form animated fadeInDown">
            <div className="form">
              <h1 className="title">Entre na sua conta</h1>

              {message &&
                <div className="alert">
                  <p>{message}</p>
                </div>
              }
              <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input ref={emailRef} type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                <input ref={senhaRef} type="password" placeholder="Senha"/>
                <button className="btn btn-block">Entrar</button>
                <p className="message">
                  Não registrado? <Link to="/signup">Crie uma conta!</Link>
                </p>

                {errors &&
                  <div className="alert">
                    {Object.keys(errors).map(key => (
                      <p key={key}>{errors[key][0]}</p>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                }
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

error received:

The GET method is not supported for route api/Login. Supported methods: POST.

[image]

Error console:

> login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Login'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Login.jsx:25     POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Login
> net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

Network:

[image]

I tried several solutions on this platform but they all told me that both methods should be the same from both the API and the front. But it's already like this in my code, I don't know why the error appears

Comment: Are you certain that the Axios call definitely caused this? It seems unlikely. One cause could be if your `<form` submits normally, without axios, because then (in the absence of a `method` attribute on the form tag) it would sent a GET. This could occur if there is a JS error or something prevents the OnSubmit handler from binding to the form properly. If you are seeing that error screen fully in the browser it does suggest that the request to the server was not as a result of a background axios request. I suggest using the browser's Console and Network tools to debug your frontend code.

Comment: login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
127.0.0.1:8000/api/Login:1     Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED


I get this on my console

Comment: Ok. Sounds like you need to enable CORS in your PHP application then, since the react app is on a different port - this makes it a cross-origin request, even if they're  on the same server/domain.